# Java Singleton Object Multiple Language Data Implement

Tags: java, singleton, multiple-languages

Assume there is a simple class:

```
public class SingletonClass {
    private static SingletonClass singObj;

    private string variable1;
    private string variable2;
    .....

    public static synchronized SingletonClass getInstance() {
        if (singObj == null) {
            singObj = new SingletonClass();
        }
        return singObj;
    }
}
```

If there are lot of string variables and they need to be stored in multiple language, what's the standard method to manage this in Java?

Currently i use:

```
public class SingletonClass {
    private static SingletonClass singObj_LANG1;
    private static SingletonClass singObj_LANG2;
    private static SingletonClass singObj_LANG3;

    private string variable1;
    private string variable2;
    .....

    public static synchronized SingletonClass getInstance(String lang) {
        if (lang.equals("English")) {
            if (singObj_LANG1 == null) {
                singObj_LANG1 = new SingletonClass();
            }
            return singObj_LANG1;
        }else if (lang.equals("Chinese")) {
            if (singObj_LANG2 == null) {
                singObj_LANG2 = new SingletonClass();
            }
            return singObj_LANG2;
        }else{
            if (singObj_LANG3 == null) {
                singObj_LANG3 = new SingletonClass();
            }
            return singObj_LANG3;
        }
    }
}
```

which i think is a bad practice, any better implementation?

Answer (score 6):

What you need is [internationalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html)

> Internationalization is the process of designing an application so
>   that it can be adapted to various languages and regions without
>   engineering changes. Sometimes the term internationalization is
>   abbreviated as i18n, because there are 18 letters between the first
>   "i" and the last "n."

Instead of a string variable for lang you need to use [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).
You store the messages in a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

> Resource bundles contain locale-specific objects. When your program needs a
>   locale-specific resource, a String for example, your program can load
>   it from the resource bundle that is appropriate for the current user's
>   locale. In this way, you can write program code that is largely
>   independent of the user's locale isolating most, if not all, of the
>   locale-specific information in resource bundles. This allows you to
>   write programs that can:
>
> be easily localized, or translated, into different languages handle
>   multiple locales at once be easily modified later to support even more
>   locales

The Java Platform provides two subclasses of `ResourceBundle`, `ListResourceBundle` and `PropertyResourceBundle`, that provide a fairly simple way to create resources. `ListResourceBundle` manages its resource as a list of key/value pairs. `PropertyResourceBundle` uses a properties file to manage its resources.

What i recommend is the `PropertyResourceBundle` because you should be keeping your translated values in a properties file.

A properties file is a simple text file. You can create and maintain a properties file with just about any text editor.

Read more [backing a ResourceBundle with Properties Files here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)
You can read [more about the concept here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html).

In the end you will end up getting the messing like this:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
System.out.println(messages.getString("locale.language.key.example"));
```

The links i provided represent lessons in a wider course on internationalization. You can navigate and read more about it there and you will end up learning the best practices. Using a framework it becomes even easier.

Taking this approach you will be using a single class.

Comment: It seems values needs to be initialized at the beginning?

Comment: You write values inside the properties files anytime, not just within a running application. Resource bundles just need to point to these files, but they need to be initialized with a locale or default. The scope of the resource bundle object depends on your need and how you set it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the Singleton approach at all. Java Internationalization is what you need:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Map as storage for your language-specific singletons

```
private static Map<String, TheClass> map = new HashMap<>();
public static SingletonClass getInstance(String lang) {
    synchronized(map){
        if(map.containsKey(lang)) return map.get(lang);
        else{
            SomeClass it = new SomeClass();
            map.put(lang, it);
            return it;
        }
    }
}
```

But the better solution for your problem is Internationalization (see other answers)